# astroid integration

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to integration about astroid, equation this: $x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=1$
I know the total length is $4\times \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}\  dx=6$ and $y'=\frac{-\sqrt{1-x^{2/3}}}{x^{1/3}}$
But, I change the interval to $\int_{-1}^0 \sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}\  dx=\frac{-3}{2}$. But length must be always positive...

Why does this happen? What's the problem?

Comment: I would wager that you issue is that you're taking a negative number ($x \in [-1,0] $) to a fractional power, which isn't particularly well defined (branches / imaginary values).

Comment: In short, there is an error in your calculation, which may come down to the sign of a square root at some point. You should get $3/2$ in both cases, because the integrand is positive and $b > a$. More precisely, the integrand is equal to $|x^{-1/3}|$, where the real-valued root is used (as opposed to the principal root). Note the absolute value, which you may have lost in translation.

Answer (score 1):

You may do it as follows: Take $x=\cos^3(t),~y=\sin^3(t)$ where $0\leq t\leq \pi/2$ (Indeed we note the symmetric of it). Now $$\ell=4\times \int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}\,dt=\cdots=4\times 3/2 \int_0^{\pi/2} |\sin(2t)| \, dt = 4\times 3/2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(2t) \, dt = 6.$$ Note that $\sin(2t)$ has period of $\pi/2$.

Comment: This, although being a nice way of calculating the length, does not answer the question.